# How to handle different language in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My application is supporting two languages, namely English and French and my single Test case supports both languages. Then phase1 is able to run the Test case in English as well as in French. So what will be the basic structure of the framework to fullfill this requirement?

Comment: No idea, did you read the Selenium documentation and search the web for that information before posting to Stackoverflow? What did they say? It sounds like something you're not the first to try, presumably there is a documented solution for this already.

Comment: Please provide a good faith attempt and an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium could support most languages. The only difference is that when You want to check page content You should use selectors without text search(so no search by text, linkText etc., which sometimes is problematic). So basic logic should be the same. Only when some pages are language specifit that could be specific test scripts.